# Searching for presence of a word in EOWL (word list)

Tags: objective-c, text-files

I am working on verifying that a word exists by searching for its presence in the [EOWL](http://dreamsteep.com/projects/the-english-open-word-list.html). I found the [CDWordList](https://github.com/cncool/CDWordList) on GitHub, but because I am using ARC, this will not work. (Unless it can somehow be converted?) I am looking for a simple way to search through a line-break separated .txt file for the presence of a word.

Note: The EOWL is separated into files by letter, so the largest file (S Words) contains ~16,000 words.

Comment: I understood you want to separate words based on line break i.e. \n. If this is your problem then you can easily do by `-componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"`

Comment: I did some searching, but really don't even know where to begin with the code.

Comment: Let your string is `NSString *string=[self readFromFile];` then use `NSArray *brokenWithLines=[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];` Check this and say if working ?

Comment: Perfect! If you submit this as an answer, I'll go ahead an accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your string be

```
NSString *string=[self readFromFile];
```

then use

```
NSArray *brokenWithLines=[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```